# swift logging for iOS >= 8 with os_log and NSLog

Tags: ios, swift, logging, nslog

I want to write my own logging function using `os_log` (available for iOS >= 10.0) and `NSLog`.

I already wrote this code:

```
static func LogDebug(log: StaticString) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        os_log(log, type: .debug)
    } else {
        NSLog(log)
    }
}
```

But now I get the exception that StaticString can not be converted to normal String. Do you know how to solve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument of both `os_log()` and `NSLog()` is a *format string*, and contains
[format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) (starting with `%`) which are expanded by the following variable argument list.

To log an arbitrary string, use the `%@` format, followed by the 
string. Otherwise it can crash or produce wrong output if the string contains `%` characters:

```
func LogDebug(log: String) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, macOS 10.12, *) {
        os_log("%@", type: .debug, log)
    } else {
        NSLog("%@", log)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
static func LogDebug(log: StaticString) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        os_log(log, type: .debug)
    } else {
        NSLog(String(describing: log))
    }
}
```

Comment: if I do that I get the following compile error: `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'StaticString'`

Comment: that means you are passing `StaticString` while calling this function.

Comment: no it does not. I'm not calling this function yet - it's a compile error.

Comment: If I try that I get the following error: `'stringValue' is unavailable: use the 'String(_:)' initializer`